# Засланный казачок

Tags: этимология

Прочитал вопрос о "ряженых казаках" и подумал: а почему мальчиков на посылках называли казачками? Какое отношение они имеют к казакам?

Answer (score 1):

Их в казакины одевали - именно такой мальчик-слуга и назывался казачком. Казакин - от казак, это да.
Вот откуда сам этот обычай пошел - сказать трудно. Может, действительно имитировали этническую принадлежность к казакам (хотя это еще вопрос, отдельный ли это этнос), может потому что казаки воспринимались как преданные слуги...

Comment: Как-то  сомнительно...

Comment: Может  просто  -  одели  в  казакин,  вот  и  казачок.  Хотя  это  и  есть  имитация  этнической  принадлежности.  А  если  термин  сначала  обозначился  на  Украине,  то  может  и  не  имитация.

Comment: Можно  наверно  сравнить  в  какой-то  степени  с  терминами  "калмык"  и  "арап".  Тоже  мальчики-слуги.   Модно  видимо  было...

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что казачками их называли потому, что они были в статусе учеников именно при казаках — опытных и взрослых. А кроме того — по этносу, который сами казаки так называют. То есть казачок — это не просто мальчик-помощник и не везде.

Comment: Казаки и сейчас претендуют максимум на субэтнос, а до революции они были отдельное служивое *сословие* в рамках православного народа (в Российской Империи делили по религии, а не по нации).